# Customizing Literate Haskell + LaTeX mode

Tags: emacs, haskell, latex, pdflatex, literate-programming

I'm having a hard time forcing literate-haskell-mode to produce PDFlatex output by default. When I use `C-c C-t C-f` it just parses the lhs file with latex binary producing dvi. I know I can always use the shell to manually run `pdflatex whatever.lhs`, but that's not the emacs way. There must be a way of customizing the default `C-c C-t C-f` behavior, but I've been googling and searching, and I still haven't found what I'm looking for.

Anyone?

Cheers;
Piotr

Answer (score 1):

I guess this uses LaTeX-mode in the backend so probably something like this should help:

```
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

This tell LaTeX-mode to use pdflatex by default.

Comment: See that's the whole problem. I have `(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)` defined in my `.emacs`, and I also tried putting local variable `TeX-PDF-mode: t` within the file, but LHS-mode still defaults to plain LaTeX.

Comment: And do you have auctex-mode installed? AFAIK this variable has meaning only for auctex and not for the default latex-mode

Comment: I do have auctex installed, but it seems like lhs-mode doesn't use it.